# Как сделать эффект "прокручивания объекта" на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать [такой эффект](https://configure.bmw.ru/ru_RU/configure/F22/2H31/FCCL1,P0300,S01CB,S01DE,S0216,S0240,S0249,S0258,S02FD,S0423,S0428,S0493,S0494,S04AE,S04CG,S0507,S0521,S0544,S05A1,S05A2,S0663,S06AE,S06AF,S06NH,S06UD,S07CG,S07LC,S0891,S08LR), чтобы можно было вращать объект по *X*? Пока на ум приходит лишь переключение картинок кнопкой. 
 
P.S. я правильно понимаю, что эти картинки машины с их сайта, это рендер модели с такой машиной?

Comment: в целом, если есть модель то и 3д можно сразу на странице нарисовать, но тут да, картинки..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а можно сделать просто рендер 3D модели с разных ракурсов, и уже этот рендер вставить на страницу?

Comment: можно, тут так и сделали...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а как сделать? библиотека или может еще что?

Comment: сделать сам рендер или смену картинок?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ сам рендер

Comment: @StrangerintheQ а почему там изображения рисуются через канвас? Нельзя просто src менять?

Comment: @MidNightElf ну, я думаю вы уже загуглили

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ можно, но тогда браузер будет выполнять запросы, может они этого не хотели?

Answer (score 0):

Drag'n drop можно использовать + набор картинок с разных ракурсов